# Get Output From trigger: Instead of Insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have this code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1]
(
    [Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [i] [BIGINT] NULL,
    [j] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL
)

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[test1_ioi]
ON [dbo].[test1] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Ids TABLE (Id BIGINT);

    INSERT INTO test1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id --[state2] INTO @Ids(ID) 
        SELECT i+1, j+'--' 
        FROM inserted;

    --[state2] select * from @Ids;
END
```

When I run this query:

```sql
DECLARE @Snd_Ids TABLE (Id BIGINT);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test1] ([i], [j])
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @Snd_Ids(ID) 
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);

SELECT * FROM @Snd_Ids;
```

The result is: 0 , 0 , 0.

The output from the trigger is not shown. Why?

If I remove the comments:   `--[state2]`

I can see two results, but `0, 0, 0` is not valid for me!

Can anyone help me?

I want to get result or output from `INSTEAD OF INSERT` and use it in other SQL statement (in same session).

Comment: Don't use `OUTPUT` (or any other operator) to return a dataset in a trigger. Returning a dataset in a trigger is deprecated and should be avoided. It will stop working in a future version of SQL Server. This is very likely an XY problem; what is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: In the body of the trigger, I calculate and re-generate some columns that is required for insert. (before insert, they must filled). So I must use `instead of insert` trigger. But, I want to get @@identity of all rows that successfully inserted, also. How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps you should be moving the logic to transform your data to an SP instead then, and using that to `INSERT` new data. Ideally triggers should not be used to transform data. The only time I find that an `INSTEAD OF` trigger should be used is when you have something like a `VIEW` with a `UNION` operator.

Comment: As a note, the behaviour you are getting is all documented: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL) - Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#triggers)